# Best way to edit a value in .csv file with specific location of value (row, column)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some code that looks through the lines of a .csv file and checks if the lines contain any values from a specific column of another .csv file.

These files look like this:

Lookup file:

```
0:  TextExclude, text, other
1:  aa,        , x ,   y
2:  bb,        , x ,   y
3:  cc,        , x ,   y
```

File where I'm looking to find these values in:

```
0: x, longtext, exclude
1: x, helloaa,  0
2: x, testaa,   0
3: x, testcc,   0
4: x, no,       0
5: x, aabb,     0
```

The output of my code is supposed to change the value of the 'contains' column from 0 to 1 in every row except for row 4.
Since my code can output the **row numbers** where a match is found and the **column number** is already defined, I was wondering what would be the best way to solve this and update the .csv file accordingly?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas
findlist = []
linecount=0
       
with open('lookup.csv', 'r') as f:
    column_names = ["TextExclude", "Exclusion", "Filename"]
    r = pandas.read_csv(f, names=column_names)
    findlist = r.TextExclude.to_list()

with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as f:
    # Skip the first line
    f.readline()
    for line in f: 
        linecount = linecount +1
        if any(listelement in line for listelement in findlist):
            print(line)
```

Comment: Will you please provide a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: With your grasp of the situation and your code, what do you think the next step is? What could you try?

Comment: The expected output would change the 'exclude' column values from 0 to 1, when 'longtext' contains a matching substring of 'TextExclude'. I would like to change the last line of code i provided to amend these values accordingly.

Comment: How about opening datafile.csv with a [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)? It'll look very similar to what you have now, `for line in f`, but you'll be iterating over a row, with individual cells. You can save all the rows to a new list, and then write all the rows out with `csv.writer(ouput_file).writerows(processed_rows)`.